# Google Sheets Query - Array formula in where clause and group by

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I want to get sum of tax value, for each unique Tax Number, Bill nos for a set of Tax Numbers
Somehow my formula is failing. Let me know what mistake am I doing.

=Query(Bills!$A$2:$CM, "Select L,C, SUM(BC), SUM(AV), SUM(CE), SUM(CC), SUM(CD)  where L  Matches "&ArrayFormula("'"&textjoin("|",1,A2:A10)&" Group by L,C ",0))")")")

Answer (score 1):

See if this helps

```
=Query(Bills!$A$2:$CM, "Select L,C, SUM(BC), SUM(AV), SUM(CE), SUM(CC), SUM(CD) where L Matches '"&textjoin("|",1,A2:A10)&"' Group by L,C",0)
```

Comment: Perfectly working. I was under the impression , we need a ArrayFormula for listing multiple values. Thanks.

Comment: @RajB, Glad to hear it worked. Since you are new here, please check out: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers